# Building Google glog with CMake on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, glog

I want to build [Google glog](https://github.com/google/glog) with CMake as part of bigger project (solution, in words of Visual Studio). What I want to have as a result:

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
   -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=xxx {MAIN CMakeLists.txt location}

cmake --build . --target install --config Debug
```

will build solution in `Debug` configuration and install files to `xxx` folder.

Ok, `glog` is sub project of main solution:

```
add_subdirectory(third_party/glog_0.3.4)
```

On Windows everything is ok ([see CMakeLists.txt](http://paste2.org/ZcJD02y2)): everything works as expected.

To build `glog` on Linux, I need to configure `.h.in` files too (among other work). CMake `configure_file` does not works: I have `.h` files but they contain `#undef`'s only. But `glog`'s `./configure` works fine, so I found that [ExternalProject_Add()](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/ExternalProject.html) may help:

```
if(UNIX)
include(ExternalProject)

ExternalProject_Add(glog
    SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/configure
    CMAKE_GENERATOR 'Unix Makefiles'
    BUILD_COMMAND ${MAKE})
endif()
```

And `cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=xxx .` works fine, but `cmake --build . --target install --config Debug` will give me:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
```

If I invoke `cmake --build . --config Debug`, then it will **build and install** glog to `/usr/local/lib`. Next try:

```
if(UNIX)
include(ExternalProject)

get_filename_component(glog_absolute_install_dir ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX} ABSOLUTE)

ExternalProject_Add(glog
    SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/configure --prefix=${glog_absolute_install_dir}
    CMAKE_GENERATOR 'Unix Makefiles'
    BUILD_COMMAND ${MAKE}
    INSTALL_DIR ${glog_absolute_install_dir}
    INSTALL_COMMAND "${MAKE}")
endif()
```

will not install files to `xxx` and just build it to `glog-prefix/src/glog-build/`.

Ok, I have no idea how to make it work.. And how to

1. specify install dir
2. lib build type (static/shared)
3. configure type (Debug/Release) - not sure that now it works

On Windows, according to glog's documentation, for 2nd case I do next:

```
add_library(${lib_name} ${lib_type} ${src_files})
if(build_shared_lib)
    add_definitions(-DLIBGLOG_EXPORTS)
else()
    add_definitions(-DGOOGLE_GLOG_DLL_DECL=)
endif()
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: In the "last try", I would try `INSTALL_COMMAND "${MAKE} install")`, otherwise `BUILD_COMMAND "${MAKE} install")`.

Comment: @Antonio, this will give the error: `No rule to make target 'install'`

Comment: I don't know if it might help, but ExternaProject_Add has a [new documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/module/ExternalProject.html)

Answer (score 1):

I will show you by example, the below is my project structure:

[image]

The file `FindGLog.cmake` in the directory `cmake` is used to find `glog`, it contents :

```
# - Try to find Glog
#
# The following variables are optionally searched for defaults
#  GLOG_ROOT_DIR:            Base directory where all GLOG components are found
#
# The following are set after configuration is done:
#  GLOG_FOUND
#  GLOG_INCLUDE_DIRS
#  GLOG_LIBRARIES

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)

if (NOT DEFINED GLOG_ROOT)
    message("set GLOG_ROOT========================")
    set (GLOG_ROOT /usr /usr/local /usr/include/)
endif (NOT DEFINED GLOG_ROOT)

#set(GLOG_ROOT_DIR "" CACHE PATH "Folder contains Google glog")

find_path(GLOG_INCLUDE_DIR glog/logging.h
        PATHS
        ${GLOG_ROOT_DIR}
        PATH_SUFFIXES
        src)

find_library(GLOG_LIBRARY glog libglog
        PATHS
        ${GLOG_ROOT_DIR}
        PATH_SUFFIXES
        .libs
        lib
        lib64)

find_package_handle_standard_args(GLOG DEFAULT_MSG
        GLOG_INCLUDE_DIR GLOG_LIBRARY)

if(GLOG_FOUND)
    set(GLOG_INCLUDE_DIRS ${GLOG_INCLUDE_DIR})
    set(GLOG_LIBRARIES ${GLOG_LIBRARY})
    message("GLOG_INCLUDE_DIRS ${GLOG_INCLUDE_DIRS}===========")
    message("GLOG_LIBRARY ${GLOG_LIBRARY}===========")
endif()
```

The main `CMakeLists.txt` use the above `FindGLog.cmake` to find `glog`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(my_caffe)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

# find glog
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)
find_package(GLog REQUIRED)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(my_caffe_test ${SOURCE_FILES})

# link glog
target_link_libraries(my_caffe_test
        ${GLOG_LIBRARIES}
        )
```

cited from:https://davidstutz.de/running-google-glog-on-travis-ci/

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays (presumably this will be in glog release 0.3.5), there is [a `CMakeLists.txt` included](https://github.com/google/glog/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) with glog, so no longer any need for ExternalProject.